# intent.putExtra passing object android studio+ firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm doing a simple crud android project
i'm absolute beginner
so i watched a tuto on youtub

i found that he passed un object to intent.putExtra

like this

```
  Employee emp = e==null? list.get(position):e;
```

```
 case R.id.menu_edit:
                        Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("EDIT",emp);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
```

code source from here https://github.com/Sovary/FireTestRecyclerView/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/hellokh/sovary/firetest/RVAdapter.java#L56

and it dosn't work with me !
intent.putExtra can't hold an object in it in my code it only support string or something
what to do to pass this argument ?

i tried to change it to char or to give one attribut but no hope hh

Comment: Can you specify what is not working or error you are getting?

Comment: intent.putExtra can't hold an object in it

Comment: For sending object in intent you need to make it serializable or parceable. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/20839582

Answer (score 0):

library:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
```

Convert your object data to string and send your data as string through intent:

```
 case R.id.menu_edit:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                        
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        //transform a java object to json
                        String employee_string = gson.toJson(Employee.class);
                        
                        intent.putExtra("EDIT",employee_string);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
```

On the destination page get convert the string to object through gson and retrive your data:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("EDIT");
//Transform a json to java object
Employee employee= gson.fromJson(json_ data, Employee.class); // here is your data as object
```